# python : how to change audio volume?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, python-sounddevice

I used `winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)` because I wanted to play sounds with a specified frequency. Now, I need to change the volume of these sounds. How can I do this? I tried to get help from `pyaudio` but...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are open to external libraries, you can use `pydub` to manipulate audio (including volume ) easily. More details [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).

Different `audio` formats such as `wav`, `mp3`, `ogg` , `mp4`,`wma` etc are available. Check [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) for more details.

Basically we convert `audio` to an `audiosegment` object and then manipulate it for various attributes using `pydub`.

`pydub` can be installed using:
    `pip install pydub`  #on 2.x and
    `pip3 install pydub` # on 3.x

Here is an example:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("your_song.mp3")

# boost volume by 6dB
louder_song = song + 6

# reduce volume by 3dB
quieter_song = song - 3

#Play song
play(louder_song)

#save louder song 
louder_song.export("louder_song.mp3", format='mp3')
```